# Integrate a Flutter app in to another flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a bigger app named X and I have another smaller one named Y.
they are right now separate from each other and they are working fine.
I want to integrate app Y in X. I want to put codes of Y in X project but they should have a different Main so I can set different themes and routes.
Is there anyway to do that?

////update////

I upvoted all answers because they are all correct.

but if you know this one please answer.
I am using GetMaterialApp from GetX instead of MaterialApp.
and it returns error

> 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 5334 pos 14: '_dependents.isEmpty': is not true.

how can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use multiple `MaterialApp()` in your project, combine the code/file like that the app is on another screen, and you will result in apps that have different references to their `InheritedWidget`s like `Theme`, `Navigator`, `MediaQuery`...

```
 /*...*/
 MaterialApp(
 /*...*/
   home: AppXHome(),
  ),
 /*...*/

class AppXHome extends StatelessWidegt {  
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Column(
   children: <Widget>[
   Container(),
   Container(),
   MaterialApp(
   home: AppYHome(),
     ),
    ],
   ),}}
```

Comment: would you mind take another look on the question?

Comment: are you using GetMaterialApp for both apps, or just one ?

Comment: Hi, so I made an app with two nested GetMaterialApp, and like you says it actually throw an exception, but when using for the first GetMaterialApp and for the second just a MaterialApp, it works just fine, and the Getx features that's related te GetMaterialApp works just fine inside the MaterialApp.

Comment: give this a try in your example !

Comment: Well you are correct at least for the most part. I tested this and all GetX features works fine this way. but there is one problem and that is GetX routing. Like Get.to
seems like there is a bug inside the GetX Package which does not work this way.

Comment: but there is a Get.context which help me somehow solve my problem.
thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 1):

You can use two MaterialApp widgets for defining separate routing ,
One for your APP X and other for Your APP Y,
Main function will remain the same no changes needed,

just create a route in APP X  for app Y and wrap your App Y code in another MaterialApp Widget where you can define routes for APP Y.

Comment: would you mind take another look on the question?

Answer (score 1):

Even if you integrate one or more apps into another app, there must be only one `main` after the whole merge.

So you need to move the other's main logic to the current one and then deal with the theme.

You can utilize this [sample](https://github.com/mitesh77/Best-Flutter-UI-Templates), which has three different apps in it with custom themes

Comment: would you mind take another look on the question?

Comment: a fresh restart could solve this, if not then share `GetMaterialApp()`